# Ember - how to convert this.get('model') to a js object

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am building an Ember component and it's being passed a model

```
{{ratings-summary-comp model=model}}
```

So you can call this model inside an action on the component's js file, like this:

```
this.get('model')
```

When I log this in the browser console, it outputs some kind of class:

```
Class {id: "1", store: Class, container: Container, _internalModel: InternalModel, currentState: Object…}
```

I want to convert this to a normal JS-object consisting of the model's attributes, so I can call the attributes like this:

```
model["attribute"]
```

This is so I can push a whitelist of attributes to an arrary inside the action.
How?

Comment: Why the hell? I am working with a whitelist of attributes and pushing them to an array. It needs to be done man @Kitler

Comment: Why not use `this.get('model').get(attribute)`?

Comment: @torazaburo Interesting, i didn't know you can call `get` on the model itself. You can post that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model is just another Ember Object. You access its properties with [get](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_get), as in

```
this.get('model').get(attribute)
```

And in the case of multiple attributes you can use [getProperties](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_getProperties):

```
this.get('model').getProperties('firstAttribute', 'secondAttribute', ....);
```

Comment: @MarcoPrins did you want an array of attribute names or attribute values? This will get you the values, if you wanted the attribute names then see my answer below.

Comment: You can also get props with Ember(model, PROPERTY);

Answer (score 0):

If you just need an array of attribute names, you can use `Object.keys` as suggested in [this post](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10875) on the ember github issues pages.

Running `Object.keys(this.get("model"))` will give you an array of attribute names.

Here's a [JSBin example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/niqemidebu/edit?js,console)

**Edit** - The post uses `Ember.keys`, but that is now deprecated in favor of `Object.keys`.